# Creating indexes prior to LOAD DATA for performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services

The [Amazon RDS Customer Data Import Guide for MySQL](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933) (written in 2009) provides the following tip to decrease load times for MySQL -

> Create all secondary indexes prior to loading. This is counterintuitive for those familiar with other databases. Adding or modifying a secondary index causes MySQL to create a new table with the index changes, copy the data from the existing table to the new table, and drop the original table.

However, there are several articles and stackoverflow posts from 2010+ that provide performance tests showing that creating indexes after loading is more performant.  Where did this come from and did it just apply to an older version of MySQL?  If so, please provide exact details.  Or, does it still apply is specific cases?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS recommendation to put secondary indexes in place before loading the data applied to older MySQL versions (< 5.5) because of the way secondary indexes were handled:

From the [MySQL 5.5 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_secondary_index):

> Creating and dropping secondary indexes has traditionally involved
>   significant overhead from copying all the data in the InnoDB table.
>   The fast index creation feature of the InnoDB Plugin makes both CREATE
>   INDEX and DROP INDEX statements much faster for InnoDB secondary
>   indexes.

MySQL offers the following recommendation in the 5.5 documentation:

> Because index maintenance can add performance overhead to many data
>   transfer operations, consider doing operations such as ALTER TABLE ...
>   ENGINE=INNODB or INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ... without any
>   secondary indexes in place, and creating the indexes afterward.

If you use MySQL 5.5 or higher with AWS, you can take advantage of the fast **Fast Index Creation** feature that significantly speeds up secondary indexes creation.

> **Fast Index Creation** is a capability first introduced in the InnoDB Plugin, now part of the MySQL server in 5.5 and higher, that speeds up
>   creation of InnoDB secondary indexes by avoiding the need to
>   completely rewrite the associated table. The speedup applies to
>   dropping secondary indexes also.